# Why do nested tuples evaluate to a single tuple but nested lists dont evaluate to a single list

Tags: python, list

In python if I have:

```
((()))
```

or I have

```
()
```

then `((())) == ()`

and

```
if (()):
    # is false
```

while

```
if [[]]:
    # is true
```

what is special about tuples that gives them this behavior as opposed to lists ?

Comment: `((),)` is a tuple containing an empty tuple, not `(())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't.

The expression `(())` is not a nested tuple, it is a single tuple surrounded by parentheses.  If you want to make a tuple containing only `x`, then the syntax is not `(x)` but instead `(x,)`.  So nested tuples would look like `(((),),)`.

```
In [1]: (((),),) == ()
Out[1]: False

In [2]: "x" == ("x")
Out[2]: True

In [3]: "x" == ("x",)
Out[3]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq):

> Tuples are constructed by the comma operator (not within square brackets), with or without enclosing parentheses, but an empty tuple must have the enclosing parentheses, such as a, b, c or (). A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,).

Parens are used in many other places in python, for example to group expressions (e.g. `(x + y) * z`). Square brackets, on the other hand, construct a list. In short:

```
() == tuple()
(()) == (tuple()) == tuple()  # outer parens unnecessarily groups the empty tuple
((),) == (), == tuple(tuple()) # the comma creates a single element tuple containing the empty tuple
[] == list()
[[]] == [[],] == list(list) # the comma here is optional since the constructor is the square brackets
```